# Decrease counter based on html element

Tags: javascript, python, html, jquery, django

I passed a integer variable as a context when i rendered a webpage. That variable is the initial number of untagged images that i have uploaded to my web application.

I then display my images in a table with the first column being the image and second column being the tag name and the third containing a button which leads to a modal that allows me to edit the tags for the images.

How am i able to decrease the count of untagged images counter whenever i fill in an empty tag?

Comment: [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are keeping track of the tag variable as well, then you can check if it is an empty string, if it is then it's untagged, if it is not then you can decrease the counter. You can loop through the list of tags to check all of them.